# Please help me for corrections

Tags: american-english

**I will available up to 1.00 pm PST.

So, you can knock me between 9 am to 1 pm PST.**

I am a little bit confused about my mistakes.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: We don't do "corrections" here.  Please explain what you find difficult or confusing about this sentence, and whatever research you have done, and we can try and help.  Side note: be aware that *"to knock [someone] up"* has a **very** different meaning in the US than it does in the UK.  It means *"to get someone **pregnant**"* :D

Comment: Which is especially humorous since you tagged this "american-english".  If you said to an American, *"You can knock me up at 9 am"*  at the very least you'd get a strange look.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence contains another error – mismatching prepositions. It should be either

> you can knock my door **between** 9 am **and** 1 pm PST

or

> you can knock my door **from** 9 am **to** 1 pm PST

But I suggest

> you can call between 9 am and 1 pm PST

which leaves it open whether to knock on your door, or make a phone call. I phrased it like that because someone knocking your door won't need a time zone.

Comment: "Knock my door" also sounds particularly British.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew sounds like a crass game show catch-phrase!

Comment: With American English (anyway), it should be *knock* ***on*** *my door* . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford oh agreed in BrE, I wrote it that way too, near the bottom, but the quoted stuff was about prepositions.